# How does toString.replaceAll work in Java?

Tags: java, replace, tostring, replaceall

For the following toString.replaceAll method, how does the parameter work so that it knows `[` and `]` will be replace by empty? What does `\\` mean here? `|` is bitwise-or, right? why logic-or `||` is not working here?

```
Arrays.toString(args).replaceAll("(\\[|\\])", "")
```

I am sure it's a dumb question, but I just don't know the keyword to search for.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: The keyword is regular expression.

Comment: No keyword needed. Just read the javadoc of [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and follow the [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) link. In short: **Read the documentation**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\`  is an escape sequence

`|` is a regex flavor `or` operator

there is no `||` in regex

`(\\[|\\])` `()` mean capture the group

`\\[` mean the character `[` because in regex this `[]` mean a list

and why we need this `\\[`

try this e.g for clarity

```
    System.out.println("absba687686[]".replaceAll("[a-z]", ""));
```

`\\[|\\]` mean either `[` or `]` character

E.g of regex symbols

`[a-z]` match all characters between a-z

`|`  or condition

`()` capture group

`{}` define range

[Oracle Regex info](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)